# mysql not like does not work

Tags: mysql, select, sql-like

I have a problem with mysql select using "not like" in where conditions. There are 15k records in table. 3k records are with value 'test' in column col1.

This select works fine:

```
select 
    *
from
    `table`
where
    `col1` like 'test'
```

3000 rows selected. This is correct.

But if I try this select:

```
select
   *
from
   `table`
where
   `col1` not like 'test'
```

0 rows selected while I expect 12000 rows.

I will be grateful for any ideas?

Comment: Can you make a small example at sqlfiddle?

Comment: not sure but try two different querry with like `col1 like '%test%'` and `col1 NOT like '%test%'`

Comment: Works fine for me: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59eb8e/3

Comment: It works fine on sqlfiddle but still not working in my DB.

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66080/3

Comment: So I solved it. Problem was in data, not in request. I didn't realize that 'not like' doesn't work for NULL value. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/17270/2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I solved it. Problem was in data, not in request. I didn't realize that `not like` condition doesn't work for `NULL` value.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/17270/2

Comment: I build a quick turnaround : select ... where COALESCE(field, "****") not like "test". This will include null values aswell.

Answer (score 2):

If you are making exact comparison as you are doing in query, you can use `NOT EQUAL`

```
select
   *
from
   `table`
where
   `col1` != 'test'
```

Comment: Thanks for idea but it didn't work. The same result of 0 rows.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
select * from table where col1 NOT LIKE '%test%';
```

Comment: If he's doing an exact match with `LIKE`, why shouldn't he do an exact match with `NOT LIKE`?

Answer (score 1):

So I solved my problem with:

`where ifnull(column,'') not like 'value'`

Comment: When answering an old question, your answer would be much more useful to other StackOverflow users if you included some context to explain how your answer helps, particularly for a question that already has an accepted answer. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SHOW TABLES WHERE col1 NOT LIKE '%test%'
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be lack of %

```
select
   *
from
   `table`
where
   `col1` not like '%test%'
```

Try without `

```
select
   *
from
   table
where
   col1 not like '%test%'
```

Comment: The 2nd solution will not compile.

Comment: You're request will not use any index a it will explore every single row in table. It will be extremly slow.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing a query similar to:

```sql
select col from my_table where not like 'some_text%'
```

and it returned no results when I expected some.

It turns out the underscore needs escaping

```sql
select col from my_table where not like 'some\_text%'
```